# When i'm modifying the scene builder with some changes..it will not effect that changes when i'm running the application?

Tags: eclipse, javafx

Actually I'm new for javaFX scene builder. When I'm configure the scene builder in eclipse perfectly and everything was fine, but When I make changes on scene builder that changes will not affected when I'm running the .fxml file. It shows some blank screen..What is problem and how to fix it.

Can anyone help me.. I'm using java JDK 1.7 and Eclipse luna.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! It's hard to guess what you are asking because you did not provide any code. Please consider to edit your question and share some code with us, so we can try to spot the problem. Please read [ask]. Anyways: Make sure that you saved the file. Have you turned on the "build automatially" setting? Try to clean you project. Stop and relaunch the project, hot code replacement may not work for fx resources.

Comment: Did you "refresh" the file before your started your app?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse when you modify a file with an external program you need to "Refresh" the project by simply click on the related button in the project's context menu or selecting the project in the projects view and clicking the "F5" keybord's button.

Comment: Isn't that the same what I asked the OP in my comment above :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't read the comments...and this is the more obvious solution. @mipa